# How do I store different profiles of users in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, django

Okay so this is pretty basic question but i couldn't find any clear answers. We are trying to do a project where every user has a profile and in the profile 5-6 attributes with sub attributes. What is a best way to store different profiles? Making tables of each user will result in 10k tables in the DB

Comment: Use a table whose primary key is the username and attribute name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE profile (
    userid INT,
    attribute VARCHAR(20),
    value VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(userid, attribute)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a UserProfile model is the [recommended way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) in Django. This would just create one table in the database. A row would be created for each user. For e.g.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    favourite_num = models.Integer()
```

This should be quite space efficient as well.